# Oracle 12C - Using Width_Bucket with Over Partition By Clause

Tags: sql, oracle12c, window-functions

I have the following dataset (simplified) that constists of a 'WORK_TYPE' and a 'TASKTIME' associated with that work type.

```
+-----------+----------+--------+
| WORK_TYPE | TASKTIME | OUTPUT |
+-----------+----------+--------+
| TYPE1     |       10 |      1 |
| TYPE1     |       20 |      1 |
| TYPE1     |       30 |      2 |
| TYPE1     |       30 |      2 |
| TYPE2     |       10 |      1 |
| TYPE2     |       10 |      1 |
| TYPE2     |       20 |      2 |
| TYPE2     |       20 |      2 |
+-----------+----------+--------+
```

I wish to use the width_bucket function on this dataset. However I want to partition the data by the work_types so each type is grouped up irrespective of the entire dataset.

```sql
SELECT 
      TASKTIME
     ,WORK_TYPE
     ,WIDTH_BUCKET(TASKTIME,0,100,30) AS TASKTIME_BUCKET
     ,WIDTH_BUCKET(TASKTIME,0,100,30) OVER (PARTITION BY WORK_TYPE) AS TASKTME_BUCKET_WT --This Errors
FROM TABLE1
```

The first width_bucket works, however buckets the values across the whole dataset.
I tried to use the `OVER (PARITION BY WORK_TYPE)` after the width_bucket, however this is causing the following error:`ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`

Any ideas?

Comment: You misunderstand `width_bucket`.  The buckets are of equal size.  So, it doesn't matter what data you are running on; the buckets don't change.

Comment: I understand i get 30 even buckets. But i want the data split by Work_type. so all the values for TYPE1 split into 30 buckets, all values for TYPE2 split into 30 bucket not TYPE1&2 split into 30 buckets.

Answer (score 0):

If you want equal width buckets for each group, you can calculate separate min and max values for each gruop:

```
SELECT TASKTIME, WORK_TYPE,
       WIDTH_BUCKET(TASKTIME, 0, 100, 30) AS TASKTIME_BUCKET
       WIDTH_BUCKET(TASKTIME, MIN_TASKTIME, MAX_TASKTIME, 30) AS TASKTME_BUCKET_WT 
FROM (SELECT t1.*,
             MIN(TASKTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY WORK_TYPE) as MIN_TASKTIME,
             MAX(TASKTIME) OVER (PARTITION BY WORK_TYPE) as MAX_TASKTIME
      FROM TABLE1 t1
     ) t1
```

Comment: This solution is giving me a more suitable looking dataset, however some groups do not have 30 buckets? I took the data in excel and created a 30 bucked histogram to check the spread of my data for a worktype, but 28 of the buckets in one case has results with 30 equal buckets but sql gives me 6 missing buckets?

Comment: @Peachman1997 . . . Some of the buckets are empty is all that is happening.